# Custom Interface for different user in DNN.. How to?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I am new to DotNetNuke; I have following situation please suggest what are the options for me to target this situation.

I have a website which is in .Net (No CMS and pure logic only) and client want it to be migrated in DNN. Please let me know how to do this? what are the steps i need to perform and how should i approach ahead?

More to this; In DNN I want to do customization per users (or members of my website); so for that which module I should choose? My customization will be like if User A logged in my website then Skin A should be shown and if User B logged in then skin B should shown.

I want to extent this scenario.

I also wanted to know how can I make my website mobile enable?

Comment: You'll generally got higher quality answers if multi-part questions such as this are split into distinct questions, as proper attention can be applied to each topic. Just letting you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make a DotNetNuke module for each bit of unique functionality (example: each report) on your old ASP.NET site.

2) Make a content page for everything else (static pages)

3) For each module that you created, create a single content page and add each module to their own content page.

4) Make sure to categorize your users with the appropriate DNN user roles

5) To change the skin dynamically based upon the user's role, [see this snippet](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3198/Dynamically-Change-DotNetNuke-Skins-by-Security-Role.aspx), from DotnetNuke Corp:

> There are a few different ways to dynamically or programmatically change the skin for a specific page load.  DotNetNuke will look first for an override value in the URL.  If  specific value is found, then DNN will load that skin and/or container on that page load.  Second, DNN will look in a local cookie to see if there is a skin being defined.  Finally, if the first two methods did not specify a skin to load, DNN will load the default skins defined by the page or site.  In the event that the skin doesn’t exist, the default skin that ships with DNN will be loaded.
>
> This is why it’s important to not delete the original skin package after installing.
>
> Probably the best way to approach dynamically loading a skin based on security role would be to create a simple cookie using either a DotNetNuke module, or HttpModule.  Either way, you will be able to retrieve the user information, and based on the IsInSecurityRole() property, generate a cookie that will in effect load the desired skin.

6) [Look at MobiNuke](http://dataquadrant.com/tabid/74/Default.aspx) for adapting your site to be mobile-friendly